# Apache Alias to serve /blog from another directory

Tags: apache-2.2, php, configuration, alias

I'm upgrading our website, the blog hasn't been done yet so I want everything starting with www.mydomain.com/blog* to use the code under a specific directory (var/www/blog) everything else will come from another (var/www/default). I have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/default/
    AliasMatch "^/blog(.*)" "/var/www/blog"
    <Directory "/var/www/blog">
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
         RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    </Directory>
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dist%{REQUEST_URI} -f
        RewriteRule . dist/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app%{REQUEST_URI} -f
        RewriteRule . app/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule .* dist/main.php [L]
    </Directory>
```

This is not working, is doing an endless redirect to:

```
/blog.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `AliasMatch` try

```
Alias /blog /var/www/blog
<Directory /var/www/blog/>
  #Options +FollowSymLinks 
  #or whatever others you want
  AllowOverride All
  <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
  </IfVersion> 
  <IfVersion < 2.3>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the <Directory /var/www/blog/> part isn't considered , instead it goes to the <Directory /> rules